# Always (node js) not always working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got myself the always module for nodejs. Now when I run my server using "always server.js" it runs and restarts like it should, however after restarting around 10 times it just doesn't restart it anymore. The process of always stays, but the process of the server itself is not there anymore since it was not restarted. Why?

Comment: just wondering - any reason why you would prefer that over other options such as forever?

Comment: Forever doesn't work, cant install it over apm and manually installing(module by module) somehow errors up on daemon

Comment: I have the same issue with forever.

Comment: Yeah, you can use always just like I did. It works, but it stops restarting as described above after the 10th time or so...

Answer (score 0):

I have used forever with nodemon without any significant issues on ubuntu.  Some other alternatives that come to mind for monitoring/restarting include:

Upstart (ubuntu): http://upstart.ubuntu.com/

Monit: http://mmonit.com/monit/

Daemontools: http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html

Launchtool: http://people.debian.org/~enrico/launchtool.html

Hope this helps.